# ActiveX doesn't work with Visual Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, activex

Hi I have created an ActiveX control in C#.net and using it in a html page.

HTML Code is :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<OBJECT id="DemoActiveX" classid="clsid:14CBF038-4D43-457e-A5D2-CBED641218C5" codebase="DemoCSharpActiveXNew.cab">
</OBJECT>
<script type="text/javascript">
            var obj = document.DemoActiveX;
            alert(obj.AddToIEList());

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I run this html page from file system (e:\testpage.html) it installs the dll packaged in "DemoCSharpActiveXNew.cab" and calls the

```
obj.AddToIEList();
```

method , but when I run it from Visual Studio it installs the dll (packaged in "DemoCSharpActiveXNew.cab") but throws a java script error saying that:

```
Object doesn't support property or method
```

Why is this happening ? Any idea ?

**Update:**
Now I updated the .inf file as per link given by @wakqasahmed, it goes like this:

When I run the web page with in local host it installs the activex control but same error

```
Object doesn't support property or method
```

is coming even after activex has been installed.

Comment: which browser version are you testing with? in both conditions.

Comment: I am testing it with IE 8.0

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your inf file is not correct.

```
opening file from file system is different from opening it through localhost
```

for reference please check this link:
[ActiveX not working on client machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14042094/activex-not-working-on-client-machine)

Comment: I am using this setting as per the reference given by you, but unfortunately it is not working. I am sure I am missing something here but just can't figure it out  
<pre>
[version]
 signature="$CHICAGO$"
 AdvancedINF=2.0

 [Add.Code]
 setup.exe=setup.exe

 [setup.exe]
 file-win32-x86=thiscab
 clsid={14CBF038-4D43-457e-A5D2-CBED641218C5}
 FileVersion=1,0,0,0

 [Setup Hooks]
 RunSetup=RunSetup

 [RunSetup]
run=msiexec.exe /package """%EXTRACT_DIR%\DemoCSharpActiveXSetup.msi""" /qn<pre/>
 I included .msi instead of setup.exe becoz it was giving some different issue.